# How to handle user likes another user logic in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to build 'likes' functionality in my app where one user (user1) can like another user (user2), and then if user2 likes back user1 they would match. What is the best way to implement that kind of logic? My current idea is something like this.

users_table

```
public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('email');
      $table->string('first_name');
      $table->string('last_name');
      $table->string('password', 60);
      $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }
```

likes_users_table

```
public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('likes_users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
      $table->integer('liked_user_id')->unsigned();
      $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

      $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
      $table->foreign('liked_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

      $table->primary(array('user_id', 'liked_user_id'));
    });
  }
```

User.php

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'likes_users', 'user_id', 'liked_user_id');
}
```

UserController.php

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $not_friends = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id);
    if (Auth::user()->likes->count()) {
      $not_friends->whereNotIn('id', Auth::user()->likes->modelKeys());
    }
    $not_friends = $not_friends->get();

    return View::make('dashboard.index')->with('not_friends', $not_friends);
}

public function add(User $user)
{
    $user->likes()->attach($user->id);
}

public function store($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    Auth::user()->add($user);

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Comment: I would make the 'like' function in the controller check whether exists some like in database from user_2 to user_1, if it does, add them to friends, otherwise just storage the like

Comment: @Gamopo Can you give an example of that function in controller? and also should I change my database somehow?

Comment: Show the code you've tried. You should have a controller method to store user_likes.

Comment: 1. Add a logic on the controller to save the likes from the currently authenticated user to a specific user.
 2. Then another method to list the likes from all other users on a user's profile.
 3. Also, there should be like button so that the currently authenticated user can like a user.
 4. Then add a method to get users who like each other.

Comment: @invalidbot Can you help on some example, especially on this (4. then add a method to get users who like each other)?

Comment: You can have a pivot boolean column (is_liked_back) in likes_users table. In this way you will only have one entry for likes getting from either side.

Comment: @rose What about setting a flag in the user_likes table, say mutal_friends which will be set when the user likes back? You can use that field to filter the mutally_liked users?

Comment: @invalidbot Ok. How would I write that logic in controller for mutual_friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a quick solution. There could be a more efficient way to accomplish this. Suggestions welcome.

My idea is to set a `is_mutual` flag for user likes. If the users like each other the `is_mutual` flag will be set.

Let's start with the migration.

Create `user_likes` table.

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->comment('user who liked this');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('liked_user_id')->comment('user whom this liked');
        $table->boolean('is_mutual')->default(false)->comment('is users like each other');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('liked_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Then, I have updated my `User` model to add the following relations

```
public function likedUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_likes', 'user_id', 'liked_user_id');
}

public function mutualFriends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_likes', 'user_id', 'liked_user_id')
        ->where('is_mutual',1);
}
```

Now Let's create a controller to handle the User Likes logic.

```
public function storeUserLikes(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user(); // Take the currently authenticated user
    // Ofcourse, you should validate the $request
    $likedUser = $request->likedUser;
    // Let's findout if the other user already likes the current user
    $isLikedAlready = UserLike::where([
        'user_id' => $likedUser,
        'liked_user_id' => $user->id,
    ])
    ->first();

    // Store the user like record in the db
    UserLike::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'liked_user_id' => $likedUser,
        'is_mutual' => $isLikedAlready ? true : false
    ]);
    // If the other user already likes the current user, 
    // they are a mutual connection. 
    // Update the row accordingly
    if ($isLikedAlready) {
        $isLikedAlready->is_mutual = true;
        $isLikedAlready->save();
    }
// Done! Now show a proper response to the User.
// I am leaving it to you :-)
}
```

Now, let's add the routes

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
    $router->get('/like-user/{likedUser}', ['uses' => 'UserLikesController@storeUserLikes']);
});
```

Now, add some users to your database (for testing). Refer Laravel database seeding and factory for more details.

How it works

The logged-in user can go to `DOMAIN/user/like-user/x` to like a user.
Where x is the id of the User to be liked.

> Note: I have added a get route for ease. You can use POST/GET methods of your choice.

Now, Let's find a list of mutual friends from the DB

Add a function to the `UserLikes` controller.

```
/**
* This function will return a JSON Response with mutually liked users 
* for the current logged in user.
**/
public function listLikedUsers()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'data' => $user->mutualFriends()->get()
    ]);
}
```

Now add a route for getting the mutually liked users. Just below the current route add the following `GET` route
`$router->get('/likes', ['uses' => 'UserLikesController@listLikedUsers']);`

Comment: Thank you this is great!

Comment: Happy to hear that it helped you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate me some things in this? What exactly does $alreadyLiked variable return and how do I get USERID_OF_B and USERID_OF_A and when I get that how can I set 'is_mutual_like' to 1 so it be true?

Comment: @mrmar I have updated my answer with fully functional code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a pivot boolean column (is_liked_back) in likes_users table. In this way you will only have one entry for likes getting from either side.